# Add text to registration form

Tags: overrides, language

I'm running Joomla 3.4.8 and I want to add some informational text on the registration form.

Here was my plan:

1. Add a new Language Override, `REGISTER_NOTE1`, with the text I want to display.
2. Find where the `COM_USERS_REGISTER_REQUIRED` was being rendered and display my override in a similar fashion after copying the file to a template override.

The problem is I can't find where `COM_USERS_REGISTER_REQUIRED` is being rendered.

I expected it in `components/com_users/views/registration/tmpl/default.php` but I didn't find it there.

I have read everything I can find googling for answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can find this string in this file - 
`/components/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml`

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: That is specifically what I was looking for. I wasn't looking in "models" due to previous posts on the internet that indicated the file would be "default.php". I have learned something! Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :) please accept the answer so that it can also help others :)